# Google Maps iOS custom UIView instead of a marker

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm looking for a way to use a custom UIView (not just a custom image) instead of default marker provided by Google Maps iOS SDK. Basically I need a possibility to place my UIView agains proper coordinates of the map, so not necessarily to use markers as they are, just any suitable solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is not currently a way to do this. You can view the relevent feature request (and star it, to show interest) here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5203

Comment: Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129206/cant-interact-with-custom-infowindow-in-google-map/32704723

Answer (score 0):

The marker only shows an image. So it cannot take a CustomView. Moreover, if your custom view has some sort of button on it there is no way you can track the events from those button.

In simple words the map renders the markers as UIImage.